# changing font-size and line-heigth wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts

I tried changing fontsize and line-height of all blog-posts, but doesnt work. What am I doing wrong?

Example Page: http://neuronade.com/kopie-sdfsdf-3

Tried Code:

```css
    .mk-single-content{
  line-height: 1.5em !important;
  font-size: 120% !important;
}
```

Comment: Appears to be working fine when I looked, used inspector in Chrome and edited your CSS and that worked as well, I can see no problems :)

Comment: Can you empty your browser cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change that selector to

```
.mk-single-content * {
  line-height: 1.5em !important;
  font-size: 120% !important;
}
```

This selects *all* elements inside the `.mk-single-content` elements. If you only want to address particular elements inside, use their tags instead of "*"

Answer (score 1):

You have to target each element inside the mk-single-content div.

For example:

```
.mk-single-content p {
  font-size: 120%;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this styling is working perfectly. May be you need to clear cache.